# Why isn't my callback function being evoked when using the Google Distance Matrix Service API

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-distancematrix-api

The below code works fine except the `callback` function is not being evoked. None of the alerts in the `callback` function are displayed but the `Start` and `End` alerts both appear. I've checked the console and Google returns the data you'd expect, example below.

My concerns are;

- What is the strange code before the Google response (`/**/_xdc_._6ct5vb && _xdc_._6ct5vb(`)
- What is the URL parameter `callback=initMap` doing when including the Google javascript file?

Google Response:

```
/**/_xdc_._6ct5vb && _xdc_._6ct5vb( {
   "destination_addresses" : [ "Church Street, Liverpool L36 9TJ, UK" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Ashmount Rd, Liverpool L17 0BZ, UK" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "5.1 mi",
                  "value" : 8175
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "16 mins",
                  "value" : 959
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
 )
```

Javascript/jQuery:

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<?php echo GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY; ?>&callback=initMap" type="text/javascript"></script><!-- Google Maps -->

  <script>
$( document ).ready(function() {

// validate form
$( "#add_employee_mileage" ).validate({
errorClass: "error-class"
});

$( "#calculateMileage" ).click(function() {
    
alert('Start');
  
var origin = $( "#employee_mileage_start_postcode" ).val();
var destination = $( "#employee_mileage_end_postcode" ).val();

var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();

service.getDistanceMatrix(
    {
        origins: [origin],
        destinations: [destination],
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
        unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
        avoidHighways: false,
        avoidTolls: false
    }, 
    callback
);
  
function callback(response, status) {
    
    alert('Callback');

    if(status=="OK") {
        alert('Ok');
        alert(response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.value);
        $( "#employee_mileage_mileage" ).val(response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.value);
    } else {
        alert("Error: " + status);
    }
    
}

alert('End');
  
});

});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
  <form id="add_employee_mileage" name="add_employee_mileage" action="https://www.system-uk.com/admin-area/ajax/add_employee_mileage.php" method="post"><fieldset>
<legend>Mileage Details</legend>

<table class="nobord"><tr><td><table class="nobord"><tr>
    <td class="bold">Employee</td>
    <td class="bold">Vehicle</td>
    <td class="bold">Start Postcode</td>
    <td class="bold">End Postcode</td>
    <td class="bold">Mileage</td>
    <td class="bold">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td><select id="employee_mileage_employee_id" name="employee_mileage_employee_id" required></select></td>
    <td><select id="employee_mileage_vehicle_id" name="employee_mileage_vehicle_id" required></select></td><td><input type="text" id="employee_mileage_start_postcode" name="employee_mileage_start_postcode" maxlength="8" style="width:85px;" value="L17" required></td><td><input type="text" id="employee_mileage_end_postcode" name="employee_mileage_end_postcode" maxlength="8" style="width:85px;" value="L3" required></td><td><input type="number" id="employee_mileage_mileage" name="employee_mileage_mileage" min="0" step="any" required></td><td><input type="button" id="calculateMileage" value="Calculate Mileage">&nbsp;<input type="submit" value="Save"></td></tr></table></td></tr></table>

</fieldset></form></div>
```

Comment: [The posted code works for me (I get the alert that says the callback ran) (fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/ya48o1xh/)

Comment: I don't have a map. Why have you added a map?

Comment: No reason.  Why didn't you post **any** HTML?  The map shouldn't be relevant.

Comment: @geocodezip - Sorry, didn't mean that the way you took it

Comment: Does your fiddle work without a map?

Comment: I think my problem is the /**/_xdc_._6ct5vb && _xdc_._6ct5vb( before the Google json response

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/ya48o1xh/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code worked for me. Notice there is no `callback` function

```
  <script>
$( document ).ready(function() {

// validate form
$( "#add_employee_mileage" ).validate({
errorClass: "error-class"
});

$( "#calculateMileage" ).click(function() {

var origin_postcode = $( "#employee_mileage_start_postcode" ).val();
var destination_postcode = $( "#employee_mileage_end_postcode" ).val();

var distanceService = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
    distanceService.getDistanceMatrix({
        origins: [origin_postcode],
        destinations: [destination_postcode],
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
        unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
        avoidHighways: false,
        avoidTolls: false
    },
    function (response, status) {
        if (status !== google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
            alert('Error: ', status);
        } else {
            $( "#employee_mileage_mileage" ).val((response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.value * 0.000621371).toFixed(2));
        }
    });

 });

});
</script>
```